# Java association problems

Tags: java, associations, uml

Finding Java an overly complicated language.  I can't figure out this association thing if my life depended on it.  I'm specifically stuck on the Cab object +pickup(rider:Passenger): String.  I know it will return a String and here's the code I have so far.

[UML Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqM7T.jpg)

```
package cabsimulation;


public class Cab {
private double companyTotalFare;
private double rate;
private double taxiTotalFare;
private int tripCounter;
private int cabID;

public Cab(int cabID){}

    public double dropOff(int minutes){
        return minutes*rate;
    }

    public double endOfShift(){
        double sumOfFares = taxiTotalFare + companyTotalFare;
        return sumOfFares;
    }
    //public String report();
    public double getRate(){
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(double cabRate){
        this.rate = cabRate;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Passenger {
    private final double weight;
    private final boolean inFrontSeat;

    public Passenger (double weight, boolean front){
        this.weight = weight;
        this.inFrontSeat = front;
    }
    public double getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }

    public boolean isInFrontSeat(){
        return inFrontSeat;
    }

}
```

How do I write (program) an association between these two objects?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." You also must provide your question **as text**, not as links.

Answer (score 0):

As written in your instructions: define a typed attribute

```
private Passenger passenger;
```

or the like (I'm no Java guy).

Answer (score 0):

When you want to have an association between two classes, you will normally use an instance variable. In this case, a `Cab` can contain a `Passenger`. So you want to have an instance variable in the `Cab` class which is able to hold a `Passenger`. This can be done like that:

```
public class Cab {
    Passenger passenger;
    //...
}
```

In the `pickUp` method shown in the UML, you want to fill this variable, e. g. like that (unfortunately, there is no specification what String the method should return):

```
public class Cab {
    Passenger passenger;
    //...
    public String pickUp(Passenger rider) {
        this.passenger = rider;
        return "something";
    }
}
```

After you called the method `pickUp`, you can access the passenger in the cab via its instance variable.

I hope I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

usually, if you have an attribute, you have the getter/setter which are dedicated to set and to get the attribute.

If you have a method (other than a setter) with a parameter of the type of an attribute, it does not mean that the parameter will set the attribute.

So for me, it could be easier to remove the method pickup and to define a getter and setter on passenger.